# Performance of incremental update of SQL table - different approaches

Tags: sql, join, insert, sql-server-2012

I want to make an incremental update of table1 with only new records from table2. I am looking for the fastest way. Assuming that the id is unique integer, which of these three approaches is the fastest? If you can propose any other approach, please share.

Solution 1.

```
INSERT INTO table1 
SELECT * FROM table2 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM table1 
    WHERE table2.id = table1.id)
```

Solution 2.

```
INSERT INTO table1 
SELECT table1.* FROM table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
    ON table1.id = table2.id
    WHERE table2.id IS NULL
```

Solution 3.

```
INSERT INTO table1 
SELECT * FROM table2 
    WHERE table2.id > (SELECT MAX([table1.id]) FROM table1)
```

Comment: 1) The `ORDER BY` clauses either do nothing here, or else generate errors.  2) Solution 3's use of `MAX` looks incorrect to me and in any event is logically very different from solutions 1 and 2, and so not comparable.  3) Solutions 1 and 2 are logically the same and will very likely produce the same execution plan and virtually identical performance.

Answer (score 0):

The third solution is incomparably faster than two previous. But be careful. It may return different results than solution 1 and solution 2.

If you want to use 3rd solution be sure that new `id` in `table2` always gets higher number than the older one. You may apply check of the records number in both tables. I also recommend indexing id in `table1`.

Answer (score -1):

```
insert into table1 
select table2.* from from table2 left outer join table1 on table2.id = table1.id
where table1.id is null
```

Comment: isn't it the same as solution nr 2?

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. How does this answer the question of which is fastest?

Comment: I believe Mohammed was correcting your typo in Solution 2 that you want records from table 2 that are not in table 1.     Personally .. I would use Solution 2 but for my own curiosity, I would test for performance on a test machine

Comment: Incorrect, sub-queries do not "*suck*" in SQL Server, performance or any other wise.  In fact, it is extremely likely that your outer join query and the corresponding subquery-based query will produce the same execution plan.